# CharacterController jump in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I was trying to do movement script in Unity. Also I wanted to add jump, but everytime when I jump it moves up for like 0.025 on Y direction and stops the player in air*(if I am on 0 and I jump it moves on 0.02545 then 0.0543 etc...)* and I can spam Space to move player up. I added gravity but it looks it doesn't work.. I don't know how to fix it. I hope someone can help me with my problem...

Here is the function what I am using...

```
Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

public float walkingSpeed = 10.0f;
public bool canJump = true;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
public float gravity = 10.0f; 

CharacterController characterController; 

void Movement()
    {
        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
        float moveX = walkingSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float moveY = walkingSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float MovementY = moveDirection.y;
        moveDirection = (forward * moveX) + (right * moveY);
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && canJump)
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are resetting `moveDirection` every frame (when you call `moveDirection = (forward * moveX) + (right * moveY)` you aren't letting the gravity accumulate. You should instead save the vertical speed separately and add it every frame.

Something like the following:

```cs
Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

public float walkingSpeed = 10.0f;
public bool canJump = true;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
public float gravity = 10.0f;

CharacterController characterController;

private float verticalSpeed;

void Movement()
{
    float moveX = walkingSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float moveY = walkingSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    verticalSpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && canJump)
    {
        verticalSpeed = jumpSpeed;
    }

    characterController.Move((moveX * transform.forward + moveY * transform.right + verticalSpeed * transform.up)
                             * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

`transform.forward` is equivalent to `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)`